# Switch the contents of "mat-cell" based on element's value

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material2

Is there any way to check the value of element's property (in this case 
element.VerificationCode) and based on that, switch the contents of cell?

I need to show the VerificationCode in cell and if the element.VerificationCode is null then show the button to generate one.

Example

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="VerificationCode">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Family code </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()
       <!-- 1 -->
         {{element.VerificationCode}}
       <!-- 2 -->        
         <button  mat-stroked-button (click)="genVerificationCode(group.id)">
             Generate 
         </button>         
 </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to @TeddySterne's version (I believe this is the preferred way of doing it in recent versions of Angular, but I could be wrong):

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <ng-container *ngIf="element.VerificationCode">{{element.VerificationCode}}</ng-container>
  <button *ngIf="!element.VerificationCode" mat-stroked-button (click)="genVerificationCode(group.id)">Generate</button>        
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ngIf` with an else statement to accomplish it. Example:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
 <span *ngIf="element.VerificationCode; else showButton">{{element.VerificationCode}}</span>
 <ng-template #showButton>
   <button mat-stroked-button (click)="genVerificationCode(group.id)">
       Generate 
   </button>  
 </ng-template>       
</td>
```